# Low CPU and Memory utilization. Does that mean server is healthy?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, rhel6, load-average

On a fairly busy `RHEL6` server I keep noticing on average following indications

```
CPU Usage   : 2%.
CPU Load AVG: 0.4,0.2,0.1
Memory Usage: 1.3 out of 16 GB
```

This is the CPU this server has

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31240 @ 3.30GHz, 8 cores
```

Does this mean server is healthy and is not under heavy load? I would assume so but since this is always on a low end even with fairly heavy traffic I am just wondering if I could be overlooking something?

Not that I expect the server to bog down, we try to ensure we use minimal resources and serve the web pages as efficiently as possible but I just want to make sure I'm not taken for a surprise someday.

Comment: Just based on that? No. Low load/RAM use could mean your important processes crashed and no one's able to do anything on the server, for example.

Comment: @ceejayoz but everything is running fine throughout the day

Comment: That's great. I'm just pointing out your monitoring needs to do more than check CPU/memory usage. You'll want to verify it *works*.

Comment: Yep that makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers you have posted look just fine. But it is hard to tell what else is going under the hood. If the server is doing fine - meaning response times are in acceptable range, no spikes or so, everything is working as expected - then stick to the golden rule "if it's working, don't mess with it".

But if you want to do some studying, there is a great [template](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/785426-a-template-for-monitoring-linux-performance-tools-like-from-netflix-) from performance engineer [Brendan Gregg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Gregg) that describes probably most possible bottlenecks in a Linux server and commands to monitor/reveal them.

I recommend going through the slides on that page as well.

It is important as well to have continous monitoring (using something like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)), as that is the only way to find problems occuring at odd times, or very sparsely and allows you to spot trends (future problems) as well.

Edit: oh, and don't forget logs (like i just did), always check logs.

Comment: Thanks @Fox, that makes a lot of sense. And thanks for the links as well

Answer (score 2):

I can come up with two different interpretations of the numbers you posted. Which of the two applies depend on your point of view:

- This is a server which is way larger than it need to be in order to handle the load.
- This is a server ready to handle future usage growth.

What you need to pay attention to are the things, you did not mention in your question:

- Do you also have sufficient network bandwidth to handle future growth?
- Is the disk storage redundant? (RAID1 or RAID6)
- Do you have backups?
- Do you need other redundancy to prevent outages?